# Finding derivative of arc length of curve

Tags: arc-length

I’m trying to find the arc length of a curve and I only wanted to know if step 1 is correct so far then if I have trouble I’ll ask for help with my solution method

Find the derivate

$$r ( t ) = \langle \sin ( t^2) , \cos ( t^2 ) , t^3 \rangle $$

$$r' ( t ) = \langle 2  t  \cos ( t^2 ) , - 2  t  \sin ( t^2 ) , 3  t^2  \rangle$$

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake by accident, lack of sleep

Comment: I’m guessing this is right so far

Answer (score 0):

With your updated question text, your differentiations are correct. For example with the first one, you can use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to get the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$ and that $t^2$ is $2t$ to put it together to get that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{d(\sin(t^2))}{dt} & = \left(\frac{d(\sin(t^2))}{d(t^2)}\right)\left(\frac{d(t^2)}{dt}\right) \\
& = \cos(t^2)(2t)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$